# I want to disabled (click) event on mouse enter and reactive it on mouse leave in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angularjs-directive, onclicklistener

**Goal : is abled execution of `addTask` function when directive found isSelecting true**

i have a directive called `appSelectable` i want to disabled addTask on mouse eventer and isSelecting is true in the and enable it on mouse leave.

```
<section appSelectable class="todo-wrapper">
    <h1 class="todo-title">Your tasks</h1>
    <form>
      <input type="text" value="New task 1" class="input-todo" placeholder="Take the garbage out" />
      <div class="btn btn-add active" (click)="addTask('New task 1')">+</div>
    </form>
  </section>
```

here is my diective code.

```
@HostListener('mouseover', ['$event'])
  onMouseOver(event: MouseEvent) {
    if (this.botService.isSelecting) {
      this.currentElement = event.target as Element;
//here i want to disabled the click event.
      }
    }
  }
```

I have tried different things but none of them work. I have tried to get the (Click) event but its no accessible.
I have tried to create event that execute before click but that does not work too.

```
 const element = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
    const existingClickHandler = element.getAttribute('click');

    if (existingClickHandler) {
      this.originalClickHandler = element.click;

      const newClickHandler = () => {
        // Your new click event logic here
        console.log('New click event');

        // Execute the original click event handler
        this.originalClickHandler.apply(element);
      };

      // Assign the new click event handler
      element.click = newClickHandler;
    }
```

Is there a way to do it.

Comment: I have a bit of trouble understanding: You‘re trying to disable the click functionality of an element when you‘re mousing over it?

Comment: I want to disable click functionality and from directive conditionally. i can do it directly from component but the requirement it to do it from directive due so some business logic needs

Comment: But in such way, you can’t click the element anyway. What is the point?

Comment: i am capturing the element and will call the click from code. just disabling click from mouse